# Аппроксимация гистограммы Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Здравствуйте. Задача звучит следующим образом. Нужно написать подробный алгоритм аппроксимации гистограммы на Python. То есть построить гистограмму с заданным шаг интервалом. Отметить точками середины столбиков, соединить эти середины через одну линиями, учитывая фальш интервалы, провести из точек на серединах столбиков перпендикуляры к линиям, найти середины перпендикуляров, отметить их точками. И через середины перпендикуляров провести кривую.

Comment: А в чем собственно суть вопроса? Какой из указанных шагов вызвал у вас затруднения? [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: попробуйте поэтапно задание выполнять. Вычислите значения гистограммы, по заданным данным и шагу (если не знаете как, задайте отдельный вопрос только по этой части, с примером входных данных и ожидаемого результата). Затем нарисуйте гистограмму (с представлением по умолчанию) -- если не знаете как гистограмму нарисовать, тогда задайте отдельный вопрос (только об этом). Затем точки на середины столбиков добавьте -- если не знаете как, задайте отдельный вопрос, приведите минимальный пример кода, который рисует гистограмму (без точек), итд.